# Edit two objects from a single MVC view

Tags: entity-framework, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an address table and a driver table. Each driver has an address with DriverId in the address table. I have created a viewModel in which data is inserted from both tables, and I have returned a view for only the driver details with Edit, Details and Delete.

When I click on Edit I want to be able to create a view that will join both tables and display the record including driver details and address detail to enable Editing.

Here is my DriverViewModel

```
public class DriverViewModel
{
    public tb_DriverDetails Driver { get; set; }
    public tb_Addresses Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

here is my Edit method in DriverViewmodelControl

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult Edit(int? id)
{
    tb_DriverDetails newDriver = db.tb_DriverDetails.Find(id);

    return PartialView(newDriver);
}
```

As you could see this work only for the driver as I have also used driver details in cshtml file as follow:

```
@model MyGroupProject.tb_DriverDetails

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
```

My question is is it possible for me from the driver view and the edit command when clicked to bring together driver and address table for the selected record in **one single view** to be edited?

Comment: Is this Entity Framework code first or using an EDMX from an existing database? Are you using Fluent API?

Comment: pWdst yes EDMX from existing database.. Excuse the ignorance not sure what fluent API is just g.....led it

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys below is the code i have put under the Edit action

```
 public PartialViewResult Edit(int? id)
        {

            DriverViewModel driverView = new DriverViewModel();
            driverView.Driver = (from b in db.tb_DriverDetails
                where
                    b.DriverID == id
                select b).SingleOrDefault();
            driverView.Addresses = (from b in db.tb_Addresses 
                                    where b.DriverID == id select b).SingleOrDefault();

            return PartialView(driverView);
        }
```

then in the Edit.cshtml i included my @model as follow

```
@model MyGroupProject.Models.ViewModel.DriverViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Driver.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Driver.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Driver.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Addresses.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Addresses.City)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Addresses.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

this has worked for me and thank you for your help